# How to find x,y coordinates of a circle in Pygame

Tags: math, pygame, coordinates, trigonometry

I am currently trying to create a digital speedometer. The project has come to a screeching halt due to the problem encountered when trying to control the dial. My variable *radial_pos* is intended to calculate the exact x,y coordinates of each tick of the speedometer and if the user presses *K_UP*, *radial_pos* will increase by 1 to show the next tick of the speedometer. However, I'm afraid its been too many years since I've learned the concept of finding the coordinates of a circle, let alone understand it enough to be able to increment it accordingly. Here is my code so far:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Screen Resolution
width = 1080 
height = 720

#Instrument Characteristics
color = (255,255,255)
background = (0,0,0)

radius_speedometer = 100
weight_speedometer = radius_speedometer-5

#Window Measurements
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
pos_center_x = width/2
pos_center_y = height/2

#Speedometer Dial Position
pos_speedometer_dial_x = pos_center_x - 60
pos_speedometer_dial_y = pos_center_y +60

#Radial Position (hint: ticks on the clock)
'''
radial_pos = ...
'''

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_DOWN:
                radial_pos=-1
            if event.key==K_UP:
                radial_pos=+1

        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_DOWN:
                radial_pos=0
            if event.key==K_UP:
                radial_pos=0

    screen.lock()

    #Speedometer Ring
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (pos_center_x,pos_center_y),      radius_speedometer)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, background, (pos_center_x,pos_center_y), weight_speedometer)

    #Speedometer Dial
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (pos_center_x,pos_center_y), (pos_speedometer_dial_x, pos_speedometer_dial_y),5)

    screen.unlock()

    pygame.display.update()
```

If anyone has any advice for this particular issue, it would greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You've given us far too much code to go through.  Next time try to get this down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have finally found a solution that works well. Here is the most updated code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from math import *

pygame.init()

#Screen Resolution
width = 1080 
height = 720

#Instrument Characteristics
color = (255,255,255)
background = (0,0,0)

radius_speedometer = 100
weight_speedometer = radius_speedometer-5

#Window Measurements
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
pos_center_x = width/2
pos_center_y = height/2

#Speedometer Dial Position
pos_speedometer_dial_x = pos_center_x - 60
pos_speedometer_dial_y = pos_center_y +60

#Radial Position (hint: ticks on the clock)
radial_pos = 70
move_rad = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_DOWN:
                move_rad=-0.01
            if event.key==K_UP:
                move_rad=+0.01

        if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_DOWN:
                move_rad=-0.05
            if event.key==K_UP:
                move_rad=-0.005

    angle = 2.0*pi*radial_pos/120.0

    radial_pos+=move_rad

    pos_speedometer_dial_x = pos_center_x + (radius_speedometer-10)*sin(angle)
    pos_speedometer_dial_y = pos_center_y - (radius_speedometer-10)*cos(angle)

    screen.lock()

    #Speedometer Ring
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (pos_center_x,pos_center_y), radius_speedometer)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, background, (pos_center_x,pos_center_y), weight_speedometer)

    #Speedometer Dial
    pygame.draw.line(screen, color, (pos_center_x,pos_center_y), (pos_speedometer_dial_x, pos_speedometer_dial_y),5)

    screen.unlock()

    pygame.display.update()
```

It's not perfect (such as no zero yet), however we are now much closer to completing the first instrument of the dash cluster!